# Generate a SortedMap based on the contents of two Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, treemap, sortedmap

I am trying to generate a `SortedMap` using streams directly from two `ArrayList`s that come from a two different sources. My goal is to have the `SortedMap` store a `Double` attribute from the second list as key and the object from the first list as the value, if those objects have a matching attribute, which is checked by a helper Object.

So far, I can get it accomplished using:

```
SortedMap<Double, FirstObject> myMap = new TreeMap<>(Double::compareTo);

List<FirstObject> myList = firstDao.get(someId).stream()
    .filter(firstobject -> secondDao.get(firstObject.getObjectId())
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(secondObject -> {
            if (Helper.check(secondObject).matches()) {
                myMap.put(
                    secondObject.getEfficiency(), firstObject
                );
            }
            return Helper.check(secondObject).matches();
    }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have no use for `myList` that I am generating with that code, but so far it's the only way I have been able to populate the `Map`.

Is there a way I can populate directly to the `SortedMap` without having to generate that list?

Comment: I don't think that code compiles.  The reference to `firstObject` in your `anyMatch` lambda would be undefined.  Maybe explain a little more of what you're trying to achieve?  Also, `anyMatch` is a terminal op, meaning the stream ends there.

Comment: I updated code to be more like the actual code I am using.

Comment: So you want the set of matching `FirstObject`'s, keyed by their "efficiency" from a matching `secondObject`

Comment: i think you could use groupby and it will generate the map you want 
better to put the code that do the grouping in a method and use this method inside the group in the collectors
here tutorial for that from oracle
https://dev.java/learn/using-a-collector-as-a-terminal-operation/#anchor_6

Comment: @Taylor Correct

Comment: IIs it possible there is no matching secondobject?

Comment: I want the key from the SecondObject's efficiency to be the the key, and the value  as the FirstObject, if that FirstObject has a matching attribute from the SecondObject.

Comment: Some example input and output data would help this Question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a `filter` that causes side-effects you need to use `collect`.

One of the ways to do that is to create an intermediate Map which would associate each object returned by `firstDao` with the matching pair returned by `secondDao`.

Then create a stream over the entries of the intermediate map. Filter out the entry with an empty key (with no matching pair). And then apply `collect(Collectors.toMap())`.

```
NavigableMap<Double, FirstObject> myMap = firstDao.get(tableId).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap( // creates a map `Map<Optional<Double>,FirstObject>`
        firstObject -> secondDao.get(firstObject.getObjectId()).stream()
            .filter(secondObject -> firstObject.getAttribute().equals(secondObject.getAttribute()))
            .findFirst()
            .map(FirstObject::getEfficiency),
        Function.identity(),
        (left, right) -> left // duplicated keys would appear when there are more then one object having no matching pair (the key would be an empty optional), so we need to guard against that case by providing a merge function to resulve duplicates
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey().get(),    // extracting a key (efficiency)
        Map.Entry::getValue,              // extracting a value
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("duplicates are not expected"); }, // since the source is an intermediate map we don't expect duplicates
        TreeMap::new
    ));
```

Another slightly more concise way of addressing this problem would be to create a *custom collector* by utilizing [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html) (*the overall logic remains the same*):

```
NavigableMap<Double, FirstObject> myMap = firstDao.get(tableId).stream()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        TreeMap::new,                                          // mutable container of the collector
        (NavigableMap<Double, FirstObject> map, FirstObject firstObject) -> 
            secondDao.get(firstObject.getObjectId()).stream()  // population the mutable container
                .filter(secondObject -> next.getAttribute().equals(secondObject.getAttribute()))
                .findFirst()
                .map(FirstObject::getEfficiency)
                .ifPresent(efficiency -> map.put(efficiency, firstObject)),
        (left, right) -> { left.putAll(right); return left; } // merging containers in parallel, I'm assuming that there's no duplicates and hence there's no special policy
    ));
```

***Sidenote:*** when you need a `TreeMap` it's better to use `NavigableMap` as an abstract type. This interface extends `SortedMap` and offers a wide range of methods which are not accessible with `SortedMap`.

---

## Addressing the comment posted by OP

This ***code provided in the question*** creates a stream of objects retrieved by the means of the `firstDao` and the following `filter` will update the map `myMap` if the predicate is meat by adding a new entry (*or replacing the value of the existing one*) with `efficiency` of the **very first encountered** matching object from the stream created using `secondDao.get()` as a source.

```
    .filter(firstobject -> secondDao.get().stream()
        .anyMatch(secondObject -> {
            if (someCondition) {
                myMap.put(secondObject.getEfficiency(), firstObject);
            }
            return someCondition;
    }))
```

`anyMatch` - is a *short-circuit* operation and in case if there are the same `id` but different `efficiency`, they will be **ignored**.

This snippet from the solution above behaves in exactly the same way: `findFirst` will pick the **very first** object for which `someCondition` will be evaluated to `true` (the case with an empty optional is being treated separately afterwards, and `equals/hashCode` of the optional is delegates to `equals/hashCode` implementation of its value, so there's no room for discrepancies in the result).

```
firstObject -> secondDao.get().stream()
    .filter(secondObject -> someCondition)
    .findFirst()
    .map(FirstObject::getEfficiency)
```

And I assume it's the *expected behavior* because there is **no** mention that code provided in the question is malfunctioning in some ways, as well as there's **no** sample data (which might lead to the opposite conclusion).

Hence, the claim that the above solution doesn't produce the expected result contradicts the current state of the question, since it's based on the logic of the original code.

Until the *desired result* **isn't specified** (by providing a sample data, or describing what's wrong with the original code) I see no possibility to improve the answer.

Comment: I could be wrong as only skimmed the code, but isn't this creating map entries of `(second.getEfficiency(), second)` not `(second.getEfficiency(), first)` though of course maybe the efficiency fields match too

Comment: @DuncG Yes this creates `(second.getEfficiency(), second)` but what I need is `second.getEfficiency(), first)`

Comment: @kinad Clear, so we need the data from both objects. I'll fix that in a minute.

Comment: @DuncG You were correct, fixed that issue.

Comment: I've tested this code, and it seems it only puts the first key and value in the map, but not the remaining.

Comment: @kinad Is there multiple objects with the same `attribute`? Does the `efficiency` values are different?

Comment: @kinad Can you provide sample data with dummy objects in the question because your comment doesn't explain the issue well enough. By the way, the code you've already posted is working correctly with the same data? Because I relied on your original solution.

Comment: @kinad For each of the objects retrieved by using `firstDao` the ***code you've posted*** will put into the *map* only the **first encountered** object fetched by `secondDao` for which the predicate from `anyMatch()` returns `true`. I only moved the *same predicate* to `filter`, so if the steam is ordered the object which the code from the answer pick would be the **same**. So, I doubt that your code acts differently. And if it's not the desired behavior, and you need something else than what your code does - you should specify it.